# Маска для видео

Tags: css3, видео

Нужно поместить видео в окошко типа мобильного телефона или ноута, чтоб оно там постоянно проигрывалось, как тут:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовала вариант с маской, помещала фрейм с видео в див и задавала ей свойство

```
-webkit-mask-image: url('../img/laptop.png');
```

Но этот способ мне не подошел.
Может кто знает еще варианты? Как такое можно реализовать.

Comment: просто поверх положить PNG или SVG? [Пример с svg](https://codepen.io/SahAssar/pen/YPWxWX).

Comment: Если у вас не видео, а просто картинка ездит/увеличивается – техника та же, поверх кладется декорация с прозрачностью, а картинка увеличивается/двигается CSS-анимацией.

Comment: Вариант с маской не подошел, так как у меня инвертируется она.  видео отображается на краях, а не по центру, где у меня в пнг пустое пространство. И у меня видео, в том то и проблема, не двигающаяся картинка.